# Too many arguments provided error in NUnit

Tags: c#, nunit

I have a NUnit test that should run with 11 params but, it gives me error when I am trying to debug.

**Error**: Too many arguments provided, provide at most 11 arguments. I have tried to send these params as list in method but, it also couldn't work. What should i do ?

I changed my variable names because of the information security.

```
[Test]
    [TestCase("11111111111", "5355553355", 0, 0, 0, "1", "11111.11111", 0, "INTERNET", null, 1, "abc*@dfg")]
    public void FlowTestv2(string a, string b, decimal c, decimal d,
                                            decimal e, string f, string g, decimal h,
                                            string m, string j, string k)
    {
        FlowRequest(a, b, c, d,e, f, g, h, m, j, k);

        Assert.AreEqual(LimitInfo.ErrorMessage, "EndPointMethodNotFound:GetInfo");
    }
```

Comment: A method that accepts 11 parameters is a bug in itself. The NUnit authors are justified in placing a limit to how many parameters can be specified. Use parameter objects (ie objects used to pass parameters around) or named tuples. Just *don't* pass 11 parameters around.

Comment: This method that i called is a webservice, and this is a web service test automation. I added a service reference and I am using it, because of that I must use like that.

Comment: No you don't. Especially for web services, which accept *request objects*. Web services for air ticket searches require hundreds of parameters (fare classes, banned airlines, direct travel preferences) and yet, you only enter four parameters in the search form: From-To,Departure Date,Return Date. The big fat request gets generated from those 4 parameters. Create your DTOs/parameter objects and *map* them to web service requests

Comment: With a tool like Automapper you could even get automatic mapping,eg by flattening a structured DTO into a flat request with similar names

Comment: You can also use a [TestCaseSource](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestCaseData) to generate test data, instead of passing all parameters through TestCase.

Comment: I thank you for your advice, mapping is sounds good.

Comment: That you say was clear solver, I used Automapper and problem solved. Thank you again @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: [Test TestCaseSource("TestDataV1")]  static ServiceModel[] TestDataV1=
        {
// new Object here
        };   solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Code Example the method's signature has 11 parameters but your `[TestCase]` has 12 defined. One too much.

---

For each attempt to run a test you have to define a own Attribute as exampled in [the documentation](https://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCase&r=2.5.3).

```
[TestCase(12,3,4)]
[TestCase(12,2,6)]
[TestCase(12,4,3)]
public void DivideTest(int n, int d, int q)
{
  Assert.AreEqual( q, n / d );
}
```

But **every TestCase must match** the method's signature.

Comment: Omg @Smartis, thats the point. I missed one parameter. Thanks a lot

Comment: @BerkayKırmızıoğlu No Problem. Simply mark the answer as correct.